# urllib2 not retrieving entire HTTP response

Tags: python, http, urllib2

I'm perplexed as to why I'm not able to download the entire contents of some JSON responses from [FriendFeed](http://friendfeed.com/) using [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html).

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> stream = urllib2.urlopen('http://friendfeed.com/api/room/the-life-scientists/profile?format=json')
>>> stream.headers['content-length']
'168928'
>>> data = stream.read()
>>> len(data)
61058
>>> # We can see here that I did not retrieve the full JSON
... # given that the stream doesn't end with a closing }
... 
>>> data[-40:]
'ce2-003048343a40","name":"Vincent Racani'
```

How can I retrieve the full response with urllib2?

Comment: Site's broken.  Try in a browser.

Comment: I get the full 165K of the response when hitting that URL with Firefox 3.0 on Ubuntu 9.04. The JSON document retrieved is well formed in my browser.

Comment: Yes, the site is broken. But this is certainly a bug in both `urllib` and `urllib2`, since other tools (curl, wget) report incomplete response. It would be nice to know what is wrong in python libraries.

Comment: Ah, well, I just got an incomplete retrieval for a different room profile, http://friendfeed.com/api/room/friendfeed-feedback/profile?format=json, when retrieving it with my browser or with curl, so the response from the server does seem broken. I've sent an email to the API developer. Sorry for the wild goose chase. :-( I'll report back when he nabs the bug.

Comment: I had the same problem. Bizarrely, urllib.urlretrieve() retrieves the entire thing (and puts it in a file), so maybe there's some code in it to use

Comment: Note: my problem was a space (not %20, an actual space) in the URL.  Apparently urllib.urlretrieve() is robust to spaces, but urllib2.urlopen() is not.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Best way to get all of the data:

```
fp = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.example.com/index.cfm")

response = ""
while 1:
    data = fp.read()
    if not data:         # This might need to be    if data == "":   -- can't remember
        break
    response += data

print response
```

The reason is that `.read()` isn't guaranteed to return the entire response, given the nature of sockets. I thought this was discussed in the documentation (maybe `urllib`) but I cannot find it.

Comment: I couldn't get this example to work with the example URL given in the question, http://friendfeed.com/api/room/the-life-scientists/profile?format=json. The response is still incomplete. As I mentioned to John Weldon, repeat calls to `read()` only return empty strings, and `read()` seems exhaustive.

Comment: I only get 51.21 KB (52441 bytes) in my browser.  The site is broken.

Comment: Also doesn't work for http://www.nylonmag.com/modules/magsection/article/uploaded_images/5463_head_minnie%20big.jpg, although wget  returns the full page, and Firefox can display the jpg.

Comment: Also, although this solution didn't work for me, that's what urlretrieve does (http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#sRsuLDQ3rCI/trunk/sandbox/wierzbicki/test27/Lib/urllib.py&q=urllib%20%22def%20urlretrieve%22&l=247), and urlretrieve works for me!

Comment: The limitations of `read()` are discussed in the docs for `urllib` (http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen). The sentence "One caveat..." should be bold.

Comment: You can also do something like `response = b''.join(iter(fp.read, b''))`

Answer (score 4):

Use [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/) (or something like it) to monitor the actual network interactions - then you can analyze why the site is broken for some client libraries. Ensure that you repeat multiple times by scripting the test, so you can see if the problem is consistent:

```
import urllib2
url = 'http://friendfeed.com/api/room/friendfeed-feedback/profile?format=json'
stream = urllib2.urlopen(url)
expected = int(stream.headers['content-length'])
data = stream.read()
datalen = len(data)
print expected, datalen, expected == datalen
```

The site's working consistently for me so I can't give examples of finding failures :)

Answer (score 2):

Keep calling stream.read() until it's done...

```
while data = stream.read() :
    ... do stuff with data
```

Comment: `read()` is exhaustive. Repeat calls to it return an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

```
readlines()
```

also works

Comment: It doesn't for me. `data = ''.join(stream.readlines()); print len(data); print(data[-40:])` gives identical results.

Comment: stream.readlines() returns a list of all the lines. But I just also realized that you are using the urllib2 module. My answer was based ont he urllib module which I have been using for longer and I just double checked the stream.readlines() from the urllib module and it works properly