# Urllib2 HTTPS truncated response

Tags: python, https, urllib2, urlopen

I am trying to fetch a page using `urllib2.urlopen` (actually, I am using `mechanize`, but this is the method that `mechanize` calls) When I fetch the page, I am getting incomplete responses; the page gets truncated. However, if I access the non-HTTPS version of the page, I get the complete page.

I am on Arch Linux (`3.5.4-1-ARCH x86_64`). I am running `openssl 1.0.1c`. This problem occurs on another Arch Linux machine I own, but not when using Python 3 (`3.3.0`).

This problem seems to be related to [urllib2 not retrieving entire HTTP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824069/).

I tested it on the only online Python interpreter that would let me use urllib2 ([Py I/O](http://py-ide-online.appspot.com/)) and it worked as expected. Here is the code:

```
import urllib2

u = urllib2.urlopen('https://wa151.avayalive.com/WAAdminPanel/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fWAAdminPanel%2fprivate%2fHome.aspx')

print u.read()[-100:]
```

The last lines should contain the usual `</body></html>`.

When I try `urllib.urlretrieve` on my machines, I get:

```
ContentTooShortError: retrieval incomplete: got only 11365 out of 13805 bytes
```

I cannot test `urlretrieve` on the online interpreter because it will not let users write to temporary files. Later in the evening, I will try fetching the URL from my machine, but from a different location.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm getting the same error, using Python 2.7, on a different Linux system:

```
>>> urllib.urlretrieve('https://wa151.avayalive.com/WAAdminPanel/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fWAAdminPanel%2fprivate%2fHome.aspx')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ContentTooShortError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
...
ContentTooShortError: retrieval incomplete: got only 11365 out of 13805 bytes
```

However, the same operation can be done (and actually works for me) using `requests`:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://wa151.avayalive.com/WAAdminPanel/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fWAAdminPanel%2fprivate%2fHome.aspx')
>>> with open(somefilepath, 'w') as f:
...     f.write(r.text)
```

Is that working for you?

Comment: I am currently in a different location, and neither do `urllib2.urlopen`  or `urllib2.urlretrieve` work here.

I installed the `requests` module and it worked perfectly.

I will compare `urlopen` and `requests` line by line to locate the point of failure. I still do not know who to blame: the packagers, or the upstream (Python devs).

Comment: Note: Internally, ``requests`` is based on ``urllib3``.