# Loading html source with urllib2/mechanize in python

Tags: python, html, string

I'd like to download some html source with urllib2 or mechanize (with .read()). Unfortunately the source I want to have is quite large. I just get a string of length up to 65747 characters (with both libs). The remaining tail is not considered. This really bugs me, I don't know how to deal with this problem. Can someone give me a hint?

EDIT: Here's a snippet of the code I use.

```
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

dataHTML = ""
fp = opener.open(url)

while 1:
    r = fp.read()
    if r == '':
        break
    dataHTML += r
```

Comment: Here is full solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824069/urllib2-not-retrieving-entire-http-response

Comment: The only solutions with urlretrieve() or readlines() (I haven't tested them) are not really satisfying. Notice that all other solutions are at least not working.

Comment: This solution works.  I ran in my Python interpreter line for line.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4268012/399704

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call read() several of times:

```
b = ''
while 1:
    r = f.read()
    if r == '':break
    b += r
```

works better?

Comment: It's still not working. I added my code above. Is my use of the build_opener() command ok? Also I have to admit that I use urllib2 but this shouldn't affect your solution.